# jsPlumb Toolkit save and restore state

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I am new to jsPlumb Toolkit edition, I am trying to restore the state of the surface that is already stored using state handle. What I am doing now is call saveState() method each time that a new node or edge is dropped. My question is when and how to call the restoreState method to get old state?

Comment: Show us your attempts

Comment: What I did is that I set a  handle to store state when declaring the surface where the instance is rendered:
  stateHandle:"surface” 

then when droping a new node or edge I call this method:
renderer.saveState(“surface”);

I want to get the same state when reloading the page

Comment: show your **code**

Comment: `var renderer= toolkit.render({`

`container: canvasElement,`

`stateHandle: “mySurface”`

`});`
for saving:

`renderer.saveState(“mySurface”);`

for restoring:

`renderer.restoreState(“mySurface”);`

Comment: @Nihed Did you get the solution?

Comment: @coder no not yet